# How can this integral be rewritten with convolutions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, convolution, dirac-delta

I've got $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ bounded and I'm trying to write `$\mathtt{f}$,' a discrete version of $f$, where each element in the domain takes on the average of the corresponding interval in $f$.

Right now I'm writing $\mathtt{f}:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the following way:

$$\mathtt{f}[n]=\int_{n-\frac{1}{2}}^{n+\frac{1}{2}} f(x)\ dx$$

However, I think this can be written in terms of convolutions and comb functions:

$$\mathtt{f}[n]=\text{rect}(x)\ast \ (\ \text{comb}(x)\cdot(\text{rect}(x)\star f(x))\ ) \text{  evaluated at }n$$

Is this the same as the first definition?

---

$\text{rect}$ is the function which is zero everywhere except in the interval $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ where it is 1.

$\text{comb}$ is an impulse train $\text{(i.e., } \Sigma_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-k) \text{ ).}$

$\star$ denotes convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, from your definition
$$
\mathtt{f}[n]=\int_{n-\frac12}^{n+\frac12}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{rect}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1&\text{if }x\in\left[-\tfrac12,\tfrac12\right]\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
we have that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathtt{f}[n]
&=\mathrm{rect}\ast f(n)\\[9pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm{rect}(n-x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{n-\frac12}^{n+\frac12}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The function I had put with an extra $\text{rect}$ and $\text{conv}$ looks the same, but takes on each value over entire intervals when considered as a real-valued function. However, mine is an over-complication since the function is actually just over $\mathbb{Z}$. This is what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your notations, $$(comb \ast rect)(x) = 1,$$
$$(f\ast rect(\cdot-n))(x) =\int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}f(x-y)dy, $$
so the final convolution equals as a function of $z$
$$\int_{\Bbb R}dx  \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2}f(x-y)dy = \int_{\Bbb R}f(x)dx.$$